# Find $a$ real number for which $\int_{x_0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-ax}}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I have the following question:

1) Find for which $a$ (a is real number) $x_0 \neq 1$ and $x_0 \neq 2$
$$\int_{x_0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-ax}\;dx}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2}=\infty$$ 
2) find $a$ such that  $$\int_{x_0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-ax}\;dx}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2}=-\infty$$

My book says it's easy to see using qualitative analysis that for the first case $a<0$ and the second case $a>0$

Usually on this type of questions I solve the integral then check using limits what $a$ should be but in this case the intergral is very complex, also I'm wondering if there is an easier way to make qualitative analysis to this.

I know the function in the intergral is the derivative so I could find  the interval of where the function increase and decrease, but I don't find any relation to the value of $a$ from this.

I'll be happy for some tips how to approach such questions, how to make smart qualitative analysis for this integral and in general cases.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: For 1) and $a <0$ will do. There is no real number $a$ satisfying the property in 2).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you explain how you managed to conclude that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:
$$
\int_{2}^{3} \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2} = +\infty
$$
already.  So as long as $x_0 \le 2$ we get
$$
\int_{x_0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-ax}\;dx}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2}=+\infty
$$
for all real $a$.

As already noted in the comments, when $x_0 > 2$ we have
$$
\int_{x_0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-ax}\;dx}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2}=+\infty
$$
if and only if $a < 0$.  In particular it is convergent when $a=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain how you notice that : $\int_{2}^{3} \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2} = +\infty$ did you find the integral and checked?

Comment: I know $\int_0^1 dx/x$ diverges.  When a number is big (such as $1/(x-2)$ when $x$ is near $2$), then squaring it only makes it bigger.  So $\int_2^3 dx/(x-2)^2 = +\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is positive and there is no solution to 2).

The integral diverges for all $a<0$.

Comment: Can you explain why integral is positive means that 2 has no solution?

Comment: @JaVaPG: are you serious ? How could a positive function yield a negative value ?

Comment: You mean diverges for all $a < 0$, right? And there need to be additional conditions on $x_0$ to give a complete answer for 1).

Comment: @Maxim: ooops, fixed. It is unclear if improper integrals are "allowed".

Comment: When $1<x_0<2$ there's a pole of second order and for $x_0<1$ there's two poles, shouldn't we say something about that

Comment: @YuriyS: not necessarily. When $a<0$, for no value of $x_0$ does the integral exist.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, did you mean $a<0$? In any case, a complete answer should also include the case $a>0$ and $x_0<2$.

Comment: @YuriyS: same mistake, twice.

Comment: @YuriyS: a "complete" answer should provide a single value of $a$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, oh, you are right, I misread the question